# What was/is the purpose of the 'MONLIST' command in NTP?

Tags: ntp

Having looked through multiple RFC documents about NTP without success (of finding an answer), and a ton of blog posts stating how dangerous, evil and useless this command is, but do not explain why it exist or what the real purpose is, I started to wonder:

Why does the `MONLIST` command exist in NTP? (The author couldn't forsee what this 'feature' would be used for, but it's a feature and has a reason to exist)

What is the purpose of the `MONLIST` command in NTP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`monlist` is a debugging command that allows to retrieve information from the [monitoring facility](http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.8p8/monopt.html) about traffic associated with the NTP service.

> The reference implementation of NTP [...] allows users to request a list of hosts with which the NTP daemon ntpd communicated recently. The list, called "monlist" has a size limit of 600 entries and contains the IP addresses of the last NTP clients or servers the instance has talked to.

[(Source)](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/news/meinberg-security-advisory-mbgsa-1401-ntp-monlist-network-traffic-amplification-attacks.htm)

You don't find it explicitly mentioned in any RFC as it is a NTP *mode 7* request. [RFC 1305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1305) explains that implementations may use "*reserved mode 7 for special purposes, such as remote control and monitoring*".

The [`ntp-monlist` NSE script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ntp-monlist.html) also has some information:

> Monitor data is a list of the most recently used (MRU) having NTP associations with the target. Each record contains information about the most recent NTP packet sent by a host to the target including the source and destination addresses and the NTP version and mode of the packet. With this information it is possible to classify associated hosts as Servers, Peers, and Clients.

Besides the information disclosure problem, `monlist` has a history of vulnerabilities such as [CVE-2013-5211](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2013-5211) which allowed DoS attacks by traffic amplifiaction via `monlist` queries with a forged source address.